# Datepicker inside table validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Please help to solve this problem, i want to validate if "FROM (DATE)" is Greater Than "TO (DATE)" without disabling the Date else i will prompt the user. All answer are appreciated. I already search the possible solution to Google but i cant find.

```
Below is the screenshot and my code .

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  })
  </script>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
   <tr>
    <th>SPORTS</th> 
    <th>FROM</th>
    <th>TO</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>BASKET BALL</td>    
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>VOLLEY BALL</td>    
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>TENNIS</td> 
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>BASE BALL</td>  
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
   </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshots]

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have write the simplified code to your need. By set `minDate` greater than the `From` date to the `To` date, you don't need to validate the dates.

Here is the code:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (selected, inst) {
        var minDate = new Date(Date.parse(selected));
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
        $(this).parent().next().find('input').datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d71j3wns/2/)

Comment: Hi @Siva,

Your code are works perfectly, Thanks dude.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have solved your problem. I have done it only for Basketball, you can do for the rest I hope.

CHEERS !!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".basketball_datepicker_start" ).datepicker();
    $( ".basketball_datepicker_end" ).datepicker(
    {
    onSelect: function(selected) {
                   var fromDate = $('.basketball_datepicker_start').datepicker().val();
                   var toDate = $(this).datepicker().val();
                   if(fromDate > toDate) {
                    alert('Buddy, FromDate has to be greater than ToDate !!!');
                   }
               }
    }
    );
})
  </script>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
   <tr>
    <th>SPORTS</th> 
    <th>FROM</th>
    <th>TO</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>BASKET BALL</td>    
    <td><input type="text" class="basketball_datepicker_start"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="basketball_datepicker_end"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```